# recuperar array do localstorage e transformar em uma consulta sql no php

Tags: php, html5, localstorage

Estou desenvolvendo um recurso para adicionar e remover imóveis favoritos com localstorage.

```
//Com esse código eu recupero os itens que foram armazenados em um array no localstorage
           $(function(){
               var favoritos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favoritos"));
               $(favoritos).each(function(i,v) {
                   $('#favoritos').append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
               });
           });
```

O retorno que tenho da variável favoritos quando executo um `document.write`, são as referencias dos imóveis separadas por (,). Ex:3174,3304,3205. É exatamente isso que preciso para montar uma consulta SQL(SELECT * FROM imveis WHERE id_imovel IN ($favoritos)).

Como transformar os itens recuperados do localstorage em algo reconhecido pelo php para armazenar esses itens em uma variável($favoritos)?

Answer (score 1):

Você deverá fazer o looping em um resultado requisitado por AJAX ao um controlador PHP sendo que nesta requisição você enviou o conteúdo de `localStorage.getItem("favoritos")` o qual será processado pelo PHP.

Resumindo:

1. Interface requisita controlador informando lista de IDs favoritos;
2. Controller entrega lista de itens em um JSON a partir de uma STRING de IDs separados por vírgula
3. Interface Faz Looping na Lista

Serão duas requisições ao total: Documento principal e JSON

Comment: @gpudo, não conseguir compreender a sua resposta.

Comment: @IgorSilva você compreende a estrutura MVC?

Comment: @gpudo, sim, desenvolvimento em camadas.

Comment: Então vou tentar explicar de outro modo: Camada V coleta a lista de favoritos e envia para C por ajax. Recebe de C um JSON que é processado e exibido na V